# Resharper file header is double commented

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there any way to prevent the file header inserted by Resharper from being double commented.

I am using the default file header template and turned on Insert File Header in Code Cleanup.

(Resharper version 7.1.2)

```
// #region Copyright © 2013 xxx Systems, Incorporated
// //
// // All rights are reserved. Reproduction or transmission in whole or in part, in
// // any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical or otherwise, is prohibited
// // without the prior written consent of the copyright owner.
// //
// // Filename: xxx.cs
// // Date:     27/02/2013
// // Author:   xxx
// // 
// #endregion
```

Here is the template:

```
#region Copyright © $CURRENT_YEAR$ xxx Systems, Incorporated
//
// All rights are reserved. Reproduction or transmission in whole or in part, in
// any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical or otherwise, is prohibited
// without the prior written consent of the copyright owner.
//
// Filename: $FILENAME$
// Date:     $CURRENT_DAY$/$CURRENT_MONTH$/$CURRENT_YEAR$
// Author:   $USER_LOGIN$
// 
#endregion
```

Comment: Any particular reason you'd want/need to?

Comment: Do you have comment signs (//) inside your header template? If so, maybe you just need to delete them?

Comment: I added the template to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create template without //, it should only contain

```
All rights are reserved. Reproduction or transmission in whole or in part,
any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical or otherwise, is prohibited
without the prior written consent of the copyright owner.

Filename: $FILENAME$
Date:     $CURRENT_DAY$/$CURRENT_MONTH$/$CURRENT_YEAR$
Author:   $USER_LOGIN$
```

And then in the field "Embrace File Header into Region with Name" (just below file template) you should write

```
Copyright © $CURRENT_YEAR$ xxx Systems, Incorporated
```